# stash pop in libgit2

Tags: libgit2

`git_stash_save()` allows one to save changes, similar to `git stash`.
Is there a function to `git stash pop` the changes back?

I can see `git_stash_foreach()` and `git_stash_drop()`. Is there a way to use them to achieve this functionality?

---

Edit: Based on [nulltoken's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335418/nulltoken) answer, I would have expected following code to work:

```
void tstStashPop ( const char * repo_path )
{
  git_repository *repo;
  git_commit * top_cmt;
  git_oid saved_stash;
  git_tree * top_tree;
  git_signature *signature;

  // open a repository
  if ( git_repository_open(&repo, repo_path) != 0 )
  {
    assert(false);
  }
  else
  {
    // create a signature
    git_signature_new(&signature, "no name", "no.name@gmail.com", 1323847743, 60);

    if ( git_stash_save( &saved_stash, repo, signature,
               "message for this stash", /*GIT_STASH_INCLUDE_UNTRACKED*/0) 
       != GIT_ENOTFOUND )
    {
      // get the commit that was saved by git stash save
      if ( git_commit_lookup( &top_cmt, repo, &saved_stash ) != 0 ) 
      {
        assert(false);
      }
      else
      {
        // get the tree for this commit
        if ( git_commit_tree( &top_tree, top_cmt ) != 0 )
        {
          assert(false);
        }
        else
        {
          // checkout the tree
          git_checkout_opts opts;
          opts = GIT_CHECKOUT_OPTS_INIT;
          opts.checkout_strategy = GIT_CHECKOUT_SAFE_CREATE;
          if ( git_checkout_tree( repo, (git_object*)top_tree, &opts ) != 0 )
          {
            assert(false);
          }
        }
      }
      // remove the stashed commit
      git_stash_drop( repo, 0 );
    }

    // free signature
    git_signature_free(signature);

    // free repo
    git_repository_free(repo);
  }
}
```

There is no error being reported but the changes are not being restored. `git_stash_save()` works (I can see the message with `git stash list`) and `git_stash_drop()` also works. However, `git_checkout_tree()` produces no effect.

Also, should I free `top_tree` and `top_cmt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a function to **git stash pop** the changes back?

Not yet. Indeed, `git stash (pop | apply)` would merge the content of the stash with the current content of the working directory.

Unfortunately, `merge` is not available **yet** in libgit2.

### Update

> However, git_checkout_tree() produces no effect.

You might want to define a checkout strategy through `opts.checkout_strategy`. Default value is a dry run and won't update anything.

You can refer to **[include/git2/checkout.h](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/include/git2/checkout.h#L23-L153)** for more detail about the options.

> Also, should I free top_tree and top_cmt?

Indeed `git_tree_free()` and `git_commit_free()` would be useful here.

Alternatively, you can avoid the call to `git_commit_tree()` and directly pass the commit to `git_checkout_tree()` which will peel it into a tree.

Comment: How about any work-around? I would expect (from my shallow understanding of the libgit2) that the format of the data that is saved to be a standard one that can be applied something like a regular commit.

Comment: @TNick You may indeed be able to try to checkout the `Tree` of the `Commit` pointed at by the stash reference. However, you'll have to decide how to cope with conflicts (safe/force).

Comment: Updated the question with example

Comment: This does not seem to be enough if untracked files are also stashed. The ```git_stash_save()``` creates two commits: one for index, and one for untracked files. These two and the base commit are set as parents for worktree commit, that is also returned.

Comment: As previously written, checking out was only a *workaround*. Merge is *required* to implement **git_stash_pop**

Comment: Merge is now available in v0.20.0. Any chances of seeing a quick workaround for this now?

Comment: @RémiBenoit I think a good move would be to open a feature request in the **[libgit2 issue tracker](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/new)**.

Answer (score 2):

Final variant as a copy-paste snippet for future seeker:

```
void tstStashPop ( const char * repo_path )
{
  git_repository *repo;
  git_commit * top_cmt;
  git_oid saved_stash;
  git_tree * top_tree;
  git_signature *signature;

  // open a repository
  if ( git_repository_open(&repo, repo_path) != 0 )
  {
    assert(false);
  }
  else
  {
    // create a signature
    git_signature_new(&signature, "no name", "no.name@gmail.com", 1323847743, 60);

    if ( git_stash_save( &saved_stash, repo, signature,
               "message for this stash", /*GIT_STASH_INCLUDE_UNTRACKED*/0) 
       != GIT_ENOTFOUND )
    {
      // get the commit that was saved by git stash save
      if ( git_commit_lookup( &top_cmt, repo, &saved_stash ) != 0 ) 
      {
        assert(false);
      }
      else
      {
        // get the tree for this commit
        if ( git_commit_tree( &top_tree, top_cmt ) != 0 )
        {
          assert(false);
        }
        else
        {
          // checkout the tree
          git_checkout_opts opts;
          opts = GIT_CHECKOUT_OPTS_INIT;
          opts.checkout_strategy = GIT_CHECKOUT_SAFE_CREATE;
          if ( git_checkout_tree( repo, (git_object*)top_tree, &opts ) != 0 )
          {
            assert(false);
          }
          git_tree_free(top_tree);
        }
        git_commit_free(top_cmt);
      }
      // remove the stashed commit
      git_stash_drop( repo, 0 );
    }

    // free signature
    git_signature_free(signature);

    // free repo
    git_repository_free(repo);
  }
}
```